# Is something wrong with the Bounty system?

Tags: bug, bounty

This [question](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/q/66716/35357) currently has a 100 point Bounty, however the user who posted the Question and the Bounty only has a reputation of 21 on SA.

Since you are supposed to have 75 reputation to place a Bounty, and the points are deducted from your reputation when awarded ([Privileges-Set Bounties](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/set-bounties)), how is this happening?

Also, is a negative reputation possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, it's not broken. See the page you linked about "privileges: set bounties":

> The reputation you're using for the bounty is immediately and irreversibly deducted from your reputation.

The user must have had 121 reputation. The minute he placed the bounty, it dropped to 21.

Note that the bounty points are forfeited whether you award the bounty or not. So deducting immediately makes very much sense.

Comment: It seems I need to pay a bit more attention to _all_ the details.

Comment: No problem, the long documentation is a necessary evil. Nobody is enthralled by it enough to not overlook a detail now and then.

Comment: Cool, so you can put a bounty on someone else's question and lose the ability to comment on it!